# Magento 1 - Stop Spam Accounts from being created

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

Every day I am having 3 or 4 new spam accounts being created on my store. I have put one of the new Google Recaptchas on the create an account page but it has made no difference. How do I stop this?

Comment: If they pass a captcha... maybe they're not spam?

Comment: The names are fake and are always meaningless with 3 words and 2 capital letters at the end of each word. Email address has been the same for over 100 different names. Typical bot behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps your Captcha isn't implemented correctly. Did you use a module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Honey Spam adds a hidden field in the account creation page.

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam

Credits to [Fabian Blechschmidt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/217/fabian-blechschmidt) and contributors.

Answer (score 2):

There's a built-in CAPTCHA in Magento 1:
Configuration - Customer configuraiton - CAPTCHA 
This should help stop the fake account creation. At least it worked for me. For other types of form spam you'll indeed need an extension.

This one works well:
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/block-robots-stop-spam/